# Why does data-reactid contain a function implementation and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: reactjs

I don't know what I've done, but for some reason most rendered react elements now have a data-reactid attribute that contains a full function definition in the string.

To be clear, the code below is not particularly interesting or important in itself, nor is it anything I have created or seen. It is simply what react is putting into it's react-ids. Here's what a rendered div looks like:

```
  <div class="react_row InitiativeFunnelView react_clickable" data-reactid=".0.$function (props, children) {
  var descriptor =0 factory=1apply(this, arguments);

  for (var i =0 1; i < arguments=1length; i++) {
    validateChildKeys(arguments[i], descriptor=1type);
  }

  var name =0 descriptor=1type=1displayName;
  if (propTypes) {
    checkPropTypes(
      name,
      propTypes,
      descriptor=1props,
      ReactPropTypeLocations=1prop
    );
  }
  if (contextTypes) {
    checkPropTypes(
      name,
      contextTypes,
      descriptor=1_context,
      ReactPropTypeLocations=1context
    );
  }
  return descriptor;
}.$188.$funnel">
```

This makes reading/debugging HTML output incredibly painful.

What is causing this?

Comment: You're passing a component as a key prop.

Comment: I've looked at all my `key=` values and I can't see where that might be true. Also, it's happening on most of my components. I do sometimes extend props before passing to the child, and I have some mixins that have utility functions (but don't set anything). Anything else I can look for?

Comment: @z5h You should really clean up your code, it's very hard to follow and you have a few non descriptive names making it hard for us and you to debug.

Comment: z5h, looking at the react id it's one of the top level components.  You haven't shown any code so it's hard to say.  I've never seen this happen before, it's likely just a typo.

Comment: @limelights if it's not clear, this isn't my code. The content of the code is not important. React is generating a react-id for itself, however it does that, and this strange stuff is showing up there.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, the problem was in some places I generate views by dynamically selecting appropriate React components for the data given. I generate a key that includes `component.displayName + ...` but in one case I simply used `component`. Please post your original solution and I'll check it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to include component.displayName in a key; if it's a different component React automatically considers them inequal.